# Access element from nlohmann::json?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I want to access element from a json which is the response from one query.

The json structure is :

```
  json =   { "result": {
            "12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq": [
                20964,
                347474,
                347475
            ],
            "12ashmTiFStQ8RGUpi1BTCinJakVyDKWjRL6SWhnbxbT": [
                1992,
                1993,
                109096  
            ],
    }}
```

I want to get the 1st element(result[0]) key from result object ie `12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq` in some variable a and the corresponding array ie [20964, 347474,347475 ] in some varible b.

The problem I am having is that 1st element key value in this case `"12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq"` always changes  for every query!

Can someone show me the way how can I access it correctly?

Comment: Do you always want to get the exact key `12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq`? Or always get the first array? Pick one or the other.

Comment: https://json.nlohmann.me/features/arbitrary_types/#notes: Write a struct with your data fields in it and give it a matching from_json() function. Report back if you run into complications.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I want the key  that is present in that place ( this time it is "12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq" ..)

Comment: There isn't a consistent "first" key in a JSON object, the ordering is allowed to be arbitrary (and inconsistent between and within programs exchanging the data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.begin()` will give you an iterator pointing to the first element. Then you can access its' key and value using:

```
auto key = json.begin().key();
auto value = json.begin().value();
```

Comment: Murat Sagdicoglu Thanks.. What if I want the  fourth key ?  Do I need to do `json.begin()++.key()` four times ?

Comment: Then: `(json.begin()+3).key()`

Comment: If you do it like that, be sure that the elements are in the order you expect them to. Accessing elements by name would be more robust (Some JSON editors like to sort elements alphabetically, for example). Not a problem for a hardcoded variable, ofc.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu I got one error on similar problem . can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/74576426/20483318 ?