# Iterate using iterators on nlohmann::json? Error: invalid_iterator

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Continuing my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74570742/20483318), Now I want to insert the keys and values present in the below json into a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>>> vec;`

Keys here are this strings: `12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq` , `12ashmTiFStQ8RGUpi1BTCinJakVyDKWjRL6SWhnbxbT`

values corresponding them are list:`[20964,347474, 34747]`,`[1992,1993,109096]`

This is the json which is response from query.

```
         j =   {
                "12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq": [
                    20964,
                    347474,
                    347475
                ],
                "12ashmTiFStQ8RGUpi1BTCinJakVyDKWjRL6SWhnbxbT": [
                    1992,
                    1993,
                    109096  
                ]
        }
```

To try first I have tried to insert only first element's key and value. It is working correctly.

```
 std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>>> vec;
  auto key = j.begin().key();
  auto value = j.begin().value();
  vec.push_back(std::make_pair(key, value));
```

Now I am trying this way to insert all the key values in vector

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>>> vec;
  int i = 0;
  while ((j.begin() + i) != j.end()) {
    auto key = (j.begin() + i).key();
    auto value = (j.begin() + i).value();
    vec.push_back(std::make_pair(key, value));
    i++;
  }
```

I am getting the error:

```
 [json.exception.invalid_iterator.209]
cannot use offsets with object iterators
```

Can someone please what is the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: Looks like json iterators aren't random-access. Instead of incrementing the offset, what about `for(auto it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're over complicating this. You can iterate over a `json` object the same way you would any other container using a `for` loop:

```
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(R"({
                "12CUDzb3oe8RBQ4tYGqsuPsCbsVE4KWfktXRihXf8Ggq": [
                    20964,
                    347474,
                    347475
                ],
                "12ashmTiFStQ8RGUpi1BTCinJakVyDKWjRL6SWhnbxbT": [
                    1992,
                    1993,
                    109096  
                ]
        })");
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>>> vec;
    for (auto it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it)    
    {
        vec.emplace_back(it.key(), it.value());
    }
    for (auto& it : vec)
    {
        std::cout << it.first << ": ";
        for (auto& value : it.second)
        {
            std::cout << value << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the order of items (JSON keys are unordered anyway and [nlohmann doesn't preserve the order by default](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#order-of-object-keys)) then you can do this in a one liner:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint64_t>> vec = j;
```

Comment: Whoa... `it.value()` instead of my over-complicated solution. Brilliant! +1 and deleting my answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yep, the library does everything for you, virtually never need to do anything with vectors directly

Comment: Yeah, I have used it but only 1-2 days here and there with a few years in between so I haven't gotten that comfortable with it yet. I looked at the library code quite thoroughly a few years back and remember being impressed by how well written I thought it was.